# (asp.net) how to create calculation in rest api

Tags: asp.net, rest, api, calculation

Method: HttpPost

URL: api/Calculation/CalculratePlus/20/30

Result: 50

This is my code:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApiPostPlus",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id}",
        defaults: new { 
            id = RouteParameter.Optional, 
            id2 = RouteParameter.Optional 
        });
}
```

This is my controller (I want fixing my controllers and making models). I have no idea...

```
// GET: api/Calculator/PostPlusValue/item/value2
public HttpResponseMessage PostPlusValue(int i, int y)
{   
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    string url = Url.Link("DefaultApiPostPlus", new { id = i, id2 = y});
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(url);
    return response;
}
```

Please let me help..
thx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want correctly but you can try this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiPostPlus",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    id1 = RouteParameter.Optional,
                    id2 = RouteParameter.Optional
                });
```

then your action:

```
    // POST: api/Values/PostPlusValue/item/value2
    public HttpResponseMessage PostPlusValue(int id1, int id2)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        response.Content = new StringContent((id1 + id2).ToString());
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunate your code 404 error.. POST and GET need models to do this.

Comment: If you want a GET: rename `GetPlusValue`, for POST: `PostPlusValue`. Request url is `api/Calculation/PostPlusValue/20/30` or `api/Calculation/GetPlusValue/20/30`

Comment: That's not problem. Just Models and Controllers are a problem. I solved it... thx comment